# print vs stderr

Tags: python, printing, stderr

Are there any specific advantages or disadvantages to either `print` or `stderr`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They're just two different things. `print` generally goes to `sys.stdout`. It's worth knowing the difference between [`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) - they all have their uses.

In particular, `stdout` should be used for normal program output, whereas `stderr` should be reserved only for error messages (abnormal program execution). There are utilities for splitting these streams, which allows users of your code to differentiate between normal output and errors.

Comment: Also note that stderr is unbuffered, which can be useful.

Comment: I’d tweak the wording of your answer to replace “program output” with “non-textual or non-status program output”. stderr also should not be reserved for error messages in all cases — for example, a program that downloads to stdout, which gets piped to another program, but prints download progress into stderr (which gets to ‘break out’ of the pipe).

Comment: @JimB in what sense?

Answer (score 89):

`print` can print on any file-like object, including `sys.stderr`.

```
print >> sys.stderr, 'Text'
```

The advantages of using `sys.stderr` for errors instead of `sys.stdout` are:

- If the user redirected stdout to a file, she still sees errors on the screen.
- It's not buffered, so if `sys.stderr` is redirected to a log file there are less chance that the program may crash before the error was logged.

---

This answer written with Python 2 in mind.
For Python 3, use `print('Text', file=sys.stderr)` instead.

Comment: In python 3.5 and Windows the stream is interactive, so `sys.stderr` is line-buffered according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html?highlight=stderr#sys.stderr)

Answer (score 31):

Be careful: there are some subtleties here, including whether or not the streams are going to interactive devices. The biggest surprise is that in Python 3 stderr is line buffered (at least in Unix). For example, in a terminal window, the following prints a number every two seconds in Python 2:

```
for n in range(5):
    print >> sys.stderr, n,     # final comma to squelch newline character
    time.sleep(2)
```

whereas in Python 3, the following prints the numbers all together when the loop finishes:

```
for n in range(5):
    print(n, file=sys.stderr, end='')    # print n to sys.stderr with no newline char
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I wonder why they decided to go that route with Python 3?

Comment: It's line buffered on a terminal, and fully buffered when writing to a file.  :(  FAIL.

Comment: You can disable the buffering by specifying `flush=True` for `print` (starting in Python 3.3).

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to separate stderr and stdout when running your script by redirecting them to different files. I usually use stderr for log messages and to keep track of the flow of the program, but use stdout for more useful messages that I am going to use them later.

One another way to write to stderr is as the following example:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("Error has occurred opening a file!")
```

Comment: Cool! :)   log = sys.stderr.write; log("hello")